# Search array element values similar to mysql like

Tags: php, arrays

I have to search array element values similar to mysql like.

Array is as follows.

```
$arraydata=
  array (0=> array('data'=>1),
  1=> array('data'=>'1|5'),
  2=>array('data'=>'2|3'),
  3=>array('data'=>'1|5|6'),
  4=>array('data'=>'1|5|6|7'),
  5=>array('data'=>'2|3|4'),
  6=>array('data'=>'2|3|4|8')
);
```

If want to search "1" in array element 'data' values then the output should be return element `0,1,3,4`.
If search "2" then output should be return element `2,5,6`

Comment: It's about time you learned how to format your own questions. Please indent code by 4 spaces (or use the `{}` button to do it for you). http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: don't you need to quote `1|5|6`?

Comment: I think this is quoted and a string

Comment: Yes this is quoted string.
I want to result without using regular expression.

Comment: Check the Savetheinternet's answer

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional search parameter in [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
$array = Array(0 => 1, 1 => 0, 2 => 1);
print_r(array_keys($array, 1));
```

But you appear to be using multi-dimensional arrays -- I'm not sure. You'd be better off using a `foreach` instead.

```
$results = Array();
foreach($arraydata as $key => $value) {
  if(strpos($value['data'],'1') !== false) {
    $results[] = $key;
  }
}
```

Comment: array data element is like 1, 1|5, 1|5|6, 1|5|6|7
So the output should be 0,1,3,4 array element.

Comment: @Rahul: I am sure 'data' contain the string not the numeric values. recheck the answer if it works

Comment: Its working fine if we search 1 or 2 upto 9. But if we search 11 or 22 then its return empty result.
suppose $array data contain extra 7=>'11|12|13',8=>'22|23|24|25'

Comment: bad idea, `1* or *1` is included,

Comment: we can search '1|' or '11|' or '22|' if require.
Please suggest solution.

Comment: Actually, you don't need a foreach loop, functions like [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter) exist for a reason you know...